# Video Streaming | File Size | Progressive | Interlace | Others

Tags: video, video-streaming, filesize, codec, interlacing

I am looking at bench-marking Video Streaming Application and found out that the Video file size depends on following factors

- HD (High Defination)
- SD (Standard Definition)
- Frame rate
- Color Depth
- Progressive or Interlaced
- Codec
- Format used

currently I am looking for couple of queries

1. What is the Video file size difference if it is progressive or interlaced.
2. If 1080i means interlaced and 1080p means progressive, what does plain 1080 means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Video file size depends on only two factors. Video duration times video bitrate. The things you listed impact image quality/fidelity.

Progressive/interlace is an encoding/display technique

1080 without a suffix just means 1080 pixels high. Interlace method is unknown.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I agree that the rest points impacts the quality, but the logic I have applied was, if a particular video file is having better quality then definitely it might increase the size as well. sometime compression techniques causes loss in the quality.